# url routing ASP.NET 4 - image link problems

Tags: .net, asp.net, .net-4.0, url-routing

I am trying to implment url Routing .net 4 into my new website and am a bit of a beginner at .NET. I seem to have it working fine but I noticed an issue for images that are on the page. If i go to a page that is actually:

```
www.mydomain.com/portfolio.aspx?id=3
```

but the url shown is:

```
www.mydomain.com/portfolio/3/category/client
```

the image url will end up being:

```
www.mydomain.com/portfolio/3/category/client/images/portfolio/web-design-arc.jpg
```

when it should be:

```
images/portfolio/web-design-arc.jpg
```

and therefor doesn't show. Can anybody recognize this problem?

Comment: Instead of using using html image i tried using asp image which works fine if i hand code in the image path but as the path is coming from a database so when i add in <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "navimage")%>" /> i get the error - The server tag is not well formed.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to sort out the issue.

I had to use `asp:Image` rather than HTML image as in my note above, but managed fix the error: The server tag is not well formed by using

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "navimage")%>
```

so where I had `"` in the code I had to change them to `&quot;`.

Answer (score 0):

Use  with "~/" at the base of your url, this will always make the url relative to the base of your application. Alternatively you can add runat="server" to your existing html controls and then append the "~/", either method will work.